# How to compute the following Fourier solution?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am attempting to compute and replicate the exact solution of the Burgers equation following  [Kutluay, Bahadir, Ozdes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798002611).

The solution which is obtained after Hopf-Cole transformation is given as:

$$u(x,t)=
2\pi\nu\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\exp(-n^2\pi^2vt)n\sin(n\pi x)}
     {a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\exp(-n^2\pi^2vt)\cos(n\pi x)}$$

where $\nu$ is a constant and the Fourier coefficients are defined as:

$$a_0=\int_{0}^{1} \exp{\left( -(2\pi\nu)^{-1}[1-\cos(\pi x)] \right)} dx$$

$$a_n=2\int_{0}^{1} \exp{\left( -(2\pi\nu)^{-1}[1-\cos(\pi x)] \right)}\cos(n\pi x) dx$$

So to be more precise, how would I calculate the integrals of $a_0, a_n$ and the infinite sums ?

---

Regarding the summation, do I set an arbitrary larger number, $T$, and compute the sum until $T$? or is there an elegant way where I can simplify the summation with a formula like in a geometric power series?

For $a_0$ I can get an approximate as seen [WolframAlpha $a_0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20exp(-(2pi)%5E(-1)(1-cos(pi*x)))). I know for $\cos(n\pi)$ it's $1$ for $n=even$ and $-1$ if $n=odd$ but I'm not too sure how to approach $a_n$.

Comment: The integrals can most likely be expressed in terms of Bessel functions

Comment: Whether or not the series itself has a closed form depends on the coefficients, but I find it unlikely. Still, you'll be fine with taking a moderately large number of terms, because the exponential factor falls very fast